# Firefox: @font-face issue w/ remote fonts

Tags: google, fonts, firefox

I've been having some trouble understanding this issue.

I'm trying to use an @font-face font on a subdomain, say mysite.example.com. The "src" of the font face would be something along the lines of url('http://www.example.com/myfont.woff").

I've tried putting the CSS file on the subdomain, as well as the main domain, and in both cases Firefox will not respect the font-face. The font-face works in Chrome and Safari (haven't tried IE yet).

If I move the woff file to the subdomain, it works fine. So I think the issue is with crossing domains.

However, if I link to a Google-hosted web font, it works fine. Unfortunately, Google Web Fonts does not have the font I need.

I know the easy solution to host the font on the subdomain, but I'm trying to avoid too much duplication and would prefer to serve this font and CSS for the font on the main domain.

Any ideas on how to get this to work? Why would it work for Google fonts but not mine?

Comment: Closing as duplicate of [css @font-face not working with firefox, but working with chrome and IE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856502/css-font-face-not-working-with-firefox-but-working-with-chrome-and-ie).

Comment: You're absolutely correct, its a cross domain issue and you might find that IE9 does the same. I created fonts.mysite.com and used that to get around the problem (also helps with optimization)